# Dart equivalent of Array.prototype.map()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dart

I try to get the id's from List of Maps in Dart.
**In JavaScript** it would be something like this:

```
var list = [{id:3, name:'third'}, {id:4, name:'fourth'}];
var result = list.map(function(x){return x.id;});
```

This should give the result

```
[3, 4]
```

Is there a simple way of doing this in Dart?

---

So far I was able to do this (**in Dart**):

```
var list = [{'id':3, 'name':'third'},{'id':4, 'name':'fourth'}];
var result = list.map((x) => x['id']);
```

The result is a "MappedListIterable" (not sure what that is) and you cannot use `result[0]` like you can with a normal List. How can I make a list of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [API for List.map](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.List#id_map) and the [API for Iterable](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.Iterable) (which it returns). You can get the `n`th element from the iterable using `.elementAt(n)` or the first element using `.first`.

```
var list = [{'id':3, 'name':'third'},{'id':4, 'name':'fourth'}];
var result = list.map((x) => x['id']).first;
```

You can also turn it back into a `List` using `.toList()`:

```
var resultList = list.map((x) => x['id']).toList();
```